# How long does a GCP secret version stay in destroyed state before becoming invisible?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

When a GCP secret version is destroyed how long does it take to become invisible?

Does it ever become invisible?

Not sure if this is documented somewhere.

Comment: Why do you mean by "invisible"? https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/consistency#:~:text=In%20Secret%20Manager%2C%20adding%20a,may%20take%20a%20few%20hours.

Comment: I meant “Seeing the deleted versions on the GCP console visually”

Comment: That is an eventually consistent operation. Eventually consistent operations typically converge within minutes, but may take a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

A secret version that is destroyed never disappears from the UI as a version. Versions are numbered so even if the version could "disappear" you would still see a gap in the numbering anyway.

You can "delete" an entire Secret, and that will not be in the UI anywhere.

Comment: the weird thing on my case is that when i recreate the secret again with the same name, i can still see the versions. could it be that these are all permanent?